# Class 'MongoDB\Driver\WriteConcern' not found in /var/www/html/jobget_admin_latest/system/core/Loader.php on line 1278

Tags: mongodb, codeigniter, php-7.2, php-mongodb

I'm facing this issue while working with Php7.2 with CI (CodeIgniter) framework using mongoDb database server.

Answer (score 0):

If you got this type error when you are working with CI and mangodb,

follow some steps
1- Check MongoDb proper installed in your system or server,
2- Check php dependency for mongodb connection.

```
 you can install mongoDb dependency  
 sudo apt install php7.2-mongodb php-pear php7.2-dev
```

3- Add extension=mongodb.so in /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini file and then restart apache server

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```

4- Check phpinfo();

```
sudo nano /var/www/html/phpinfo.php
enter below code in phpinfo.php
<?php phpinfo( ); ?>
save file and run with browser
```

[image]

**Now issue resolved please restart your apache**